# How to pass a C# variable to an Access 2010 query

Tags: c#, ms-access, variables

I wrote a program that reads and writes information to/from an Access database.

**(See screenshot & code below)** , and it works great, with no issues However, I want to expand it, to be able to click an additional button, and have it retrieve all records, but prompt for a date (or date range) first. I already know how to get an Access form or an Access report to prompt, but I want the C# program to prompt for a date, and pass it to the query; then show in a resulting window, like in the picture. This should eliminate a user from having Access open when a form of Report or Form does. ANY help is appreciated, and thanks in advance to any suggestions!

[image]

```
namespace Health_Direct_Receiving
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Receiving\Database.accdb");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                vcon.Open();
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                {
                    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You must fill in all fields.");
                            return;
                        }
                    else
                        {   
                            OleDbCommand dbCommand;
                            OleDbDataReader dbReader;
                            new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Receiving\Database.accdb");
                            dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) as Record_Count from script_received", vcon);

                            dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                            if (dbReader.Read() == true)
                                rowCount = dbReader["Record_Count"].ToString();
                            else
                            return;

                            var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");



                            {
                                using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO script_received (script, qty, emp_id, received_Date) VALUES (@script,@qty,@emp_Id,@rec_date)")) 
                                  {
                                      command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                      command.Parameters.Add("@script", OleDbType.Integer).Value = textBox1.Text; 
                                      command.Parameters.Add("@qty", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                                      command.Parameters.Add("@emp_id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
                                      command.Parameters.Add("@rec_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = date; 
                                      command.Connection = vcon;

                                      //vcon.Open();

                                      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                  }

                                    this.textBox1.Clear();
                                    this.textBox2.Clear();
                                    this.textBox1.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                new Form2().Show();
            }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                new Form3().Show();
            }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        public object rowCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### Form2

```
namespace Receiving
           {
              public partial class Form2 : Form
                 { 
                   public Form2() 
                      {
                         InitializeComponent();
                      }
                   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                      {
                   this.script_receivedTableAdapter.Fill(this.DatabaseDataSet.script_received);
                      }
                   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                      {
                         this.Close();
                  }
            }
       }
```

---

Form 3

---

```
namespace Receiving 
    {
        public partial class Form3 : Form
            {
                public Form3()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }
                private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {                 this.script_All_ReceivedTableAdapter.Fill(this.DatabaseDataSet.script_All_‌​Received); 
                    }
                private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        this.Close(); 
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for Form2 and Form3?

Comment: I don't understand "This should eliminate a user from having Access open when a form of Report or Form does."  Did you mean to type something else?

Comment: Just do the same thing you do in read, only use [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to insert your parameter into the select.

Comment: @Geo, please insert your code inside the main question and not in comments, it's unreadable. (Click Edit on question)

Comment: @MattiasJosefsson: I added the code for the other two pages above.

Comment: @phoog: What I meant, was when a person clicks a button on my program, a window pops up with a "datagridview" of the table or query. When a user uses a for, Microsoft Access actually opens up, and the experience for the end user is no longer transparent. I don't want the end user, that doesn't even know what Access is, to have to worry about it. I want them to be able to filter a table with a date picker, or some kind of way that a variable of a sort, can pass into the query, and the datagridview would show that. Hope that explanation helped.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: I kind of get what you are saying, but that read query is only to create the variable "rowCount", which I never used, and should have removed. But since it's in there already, I suppose I can just modify it to use it for this post's purpose. Should I move it to another form to do what you suggest, and what would be the change in the syntax? And how does that code get passed back to a datagridview on the form? Again, ANY help is appreciated!

Comment: @Geo I was referring to the start of your question where you say your program _reads and writes information to/from an Access database_  Up to you where you place it, but the code would look something like `dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("select field1, field2, field3 from some_table where date = {0}",DateTimePickerControl.value), vcon);`

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: Hopefully, I am not confusing anyone here. To clarify, the program, on form1, obviously writes to the database. What I mean by getting info from the database is that the dataGridView uses a tableAdapter (in Visual Studio 2010) to interface between the Access table and the dataGridView. I feel like the epiphany is right in front of me, but am too ignorant to realize it! Uggh!   :)

Comment: I believe that [Shining Start - Tutorial Using Table Adapters](http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/DataSet/DataSetProject7.aspx) should move you along.  They cover creating the methods you need so that they can be called using an [Using an OleDbDataReader to Retrieve Data](http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/DataSet/DataSetProject8.aspx).